# Unable to update column with ROWNUM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, oracle10g

I have a Oracle result set like below

[image]

**I need to replace OLD_ID with RNUM.** I am using the following query

```
   merge into x u
            using (
                      select OLD_ID, FBU_FFF_FFY,FBU_FFY_MONTH,row_number() over (partition by fbu_ffy_month, fbu_fff_ffy order by fbu_ffy_month, fbu_fff_ffy) rnum 
                      from x
            ) s
            on (u.FBU_FFF_FFY= s.FBU_FFF_FFY and u.FBU_FFY_MONTH = s.FBU_FFY_MONTH)
            when matched then update set u.OLD_ID = s.rnum;
```

This gives me oracle error

> "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
>   * Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
>              activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
>   * Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Any ideas ?

Comment: shy are doing a merge? why not just update?

Comment: Is there some reason that `UPDATE X SET OLD_ID = RNUM` wouldn't work?

Comment: The joining condition returns more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have duplicates on S

Answer (score 0):

don't have your tables so I could not test but how about

```
UPDATE (SELECT rnum, old_id
          FROM (SELECT OLD_ID,
                       FBU_FFF_FFY,
                       FBU_FFY_MONTH,
                       ROW_NUMBER ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY fbu_ffy_month, fbu_fff_ffy
                             ORDER BY fbu_ffy_month, fbu_fff_ffy)
                          rnum
                  FROM x) s,
               x u
         WHERE     u.FBU_FFF_FFY = s.FBU_FFF_FFY
               AND u.FBU_FFY_MONTH = s.FBU_FFY_MONTH)
   SET old_id = rnum
```

Comment: by the way trying to maintain an order like that is going to be a nightmare why not just leave old id out of the table definition and just create a view that does your partitioning. then just select from the view

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining to itself using rowid.  Something like:

```
SQL> create table x
(
old_id number,
val varchar2(10),
yr varchar2(4),
mth varchar2(2)
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into x values (1, 'X', '2016','01')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into x values (2, 'Y', '2016','01')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into x values (3, 'X', '2016','02')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into x values (4, 'Y', '2016','02')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into x values (5, 'X', '2016','03')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into x values (6, 'Y', '2016','03')
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select * from x

    OLD_ID VAL        YR   MTH
---------- ---------- ---- ---
         1 X          2016 01 
         2 Y          2016 01 
         3 X          2016 02 
         4 Y          2016 02 
         5 X          2016 03 
         6 Y          2016 03 

6 rows selected.
SQL> -- this will update ALL rows of table x
SQL> update x
set old_id = (
    select y.rnum
    from x x2
    JOIN (
    select rowid as row_id, yr, mth, row_number() over (partition by yr, mth order by yr, mth) rnum
    from x ) y
    ON (x2.rowid = y.row_id)
    where x.rowid = x2.rowid
)
6 rows updated.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select * from x

    OLD_ID VAL        YR   MTH
---------- ---------- ---- ---
         1 X          2016 01 
         2 Y          2016 01 
         1 X          2016 02 
         2 Y          2016 02 
         1 X          2016 03 
         2 Y          2016 03 

6 rows selected.
```